# Error on sql database "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a problem with my login system. I made a simple system which worked well, but I wanted to make it more advanced and display a different start page depending on a user's `UserType`. However, I'm encountering the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable @UserType."

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class LoginwithEncryption : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from dbo.UserInfo where Login =@Login and UserType=@UserType and Password=@Password and UserType=@UserType", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPWD.Text+".123");


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int usertype = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["UserType"]);


            if (usertype == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("StartPage.aspx");
            }
            else if (usertype == 2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("DiferentStartPage.aspx");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation",
                "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid UserName and Password')</script>");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `and UserType=@UserType` twice?  Why didn't you include `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType"...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error states: Must declare the scalar variable "@UserType"

In other words, the SQL command has a parameter for `@UserType`, but there are no parameters declared in the parameters collection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"select * from dbo.UserInfo where Login =@Login and UserType=@UserType and Password=@Password and UserType=@UserType", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", txtUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPWD.Text+".123");
```

Add another parameter for the `@UserType` parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", "User Type");
```

Also, the SQL contains a duplicate reference to for `@UserType`:

```
select * from dbo.UserInfo 
where Login=@Login 
      and UserType=@UserType 
      and Password=@Password 
      and UserType=@UserType
```

Should probably be:

```
select * from dbo.UserInfo 
where Login=@Login 
      and Password=@Password
      and UserType=@UserType
```

Comment: Strange I did add cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", "User Type"); to my program, but login did stop to work. (removing userType make login work again) any idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: You have to provide an actual value for `@UserType`; in the example, `"User Type"` should be replaced with your value.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", SqlDbType.Int); Is this correct way ?

Comment: In re-reading your question, it appears you may not want to use the `@UserType` parameter; rather, you are trying to use the `UserType` to redirect based on the login. If that's the case, then just remove `@UserType` from the SQL command and don't add any other parameters.

Comment: Great! If you're so inclined, feel free to upvote and accept this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You have passed in @Login and @Password as parameters to your query, but you have not passed in @UserType as a parameter to your query.