# Must declare the scalar variable on @wachtwoord SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I got this error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable @wachtwoord
```

I tried to solve it using this post: [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647538/error-on-sql-database-must-declare-the-scalar-variable) but with no luck so far. I am a bit lost. I want the generate a code for `@wachtwoord` (password). Then I want to count all the rows in the database. I will use the count for my for statement, in my for statement will be an `UPDATE` statement to update every row in the database with their own generated password.

If you guys have any advise or a solution for this problem it would be great!

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string cn = "Data Source=pc-wesley;Initial Catalog=ProjectVoteOrDie;Integrated Security=True";
    string cm1 = "UPDATE Test SET wachtwoord = @wachtwoord WHERE id = @id";
    string cm2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test;";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnKlik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();

        //random code gen
        var result = new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                .ToArray());

        SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(cn);
        SqlCommand scm1 = new SqlCommand(cm1, scn);
        SqlCommand scm2 = new SqlCommand(cm2, scn);

        try
        {
            scn.Open();

            int rows = Convert.ToInt32(scm2.ExecuteScalar());
            scm2.Parameters.Clear();

            for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
            {
                scm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wachtwoord", result);
                scm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i);
                scm1.Parameters.Clear();
                scm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception se) //got the error on 
        {
            lblRandom.Text = Convert.ToString(se);
        }
        finally
        {
            scn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `cm1.Parameters.Clear();` after adding the parameters?  This seems counter-productive.

Comment: You need to place the clear() after execute nonquery as it will clear all assigned parameters before executing the query.

Comment: you should first call `scm1.ExecuteNonQuery();` and then `scm1.Parameters.Clear();` inside your for loop.